# Kafka: Different Deserializers For Different Topics

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am currently consuming massages from different Kafka topics using Spring Boot and `@KafkaListener` annotation.

All of the topics currently contain messages in Avro format (I'm using `KafkaAvroDeserializer`).

But now, I have to read a new topic, which contains messages in JSON format.

Is it possible to use `JsonDeserializer` with this new topic and `KafkaAvroDeserializer` with the legacy topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the following configuration for declaring Kafka listener container factories:

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumersConfig {
  @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  private <K, V> ConsumerFactory<K, V> generateFactory(
      Deserializer<K> keyDeserializer, Deserializer<V> valueDeserializer) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, keyDeserializer, valueDeserializer);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, YourClass>
      kafkaListenerContainerFactoryJson() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, YourClass> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    var consumerFactory = generateFactory(new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(YourClass.class, false));
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
  }

  //TODO: Declare bean for Avro deserializer
}
```

Where `generateFactory` method is used to generate a factory based on given key and value deserializers.
For different pairs of key and value deserializers, a new `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` bean should be declared.

Accordingly, `KafkaListener` should be declared as shown below.

```java
@KafkaListener(
      topics = "${kafka.topic.jsonTopic}",
      containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactoryJson")
  public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, YourClass> record) {
    // ...
  }
```

Where `containerFactory` corresponds to the bean name from the configuration class.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I was even able to keep the default Spring Boot configuration for other listeners, and just define this additional bean. One more thing: the "trusted packages" property produces a warning `The configuration 'spring.json.trusted.packages' was supplied but isn't a known config.`

Comment: Great! The property was added because of problems with deserializing messages received from other Spring boot applications. Consumer was throwing exception because it was trying to deserialize message value of differently named class or the class being in different package on the producer side, which was passed through type header. I also disabled type headers with property -> `spring.json.use.type.headers=false`